# Exchange 2007 migration to exchange 2010 - public folder issue

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2007, public-folders, message-queuing

-----Some info-----
 2007 Server has multi roles - CAS/HT/MBX
2010 server has multi roles CAS/HT/MBX

mail is flowing fine from all the mailboxes on the 2010 server (they were all moved from the 2007 server).

I have followed the instructions from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg576862(v=exchg.141).aspx

I have run the script moveallreplicas.ps1, and the script for adding the new server as a public Folder replica.

Even tried removing the Legacy Exchange 2003 server AD Attribute as specified here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/05/05/3409916.aspx

------The issue------
On the 2010 server, there is not even a public folder heirarchy, let alone any content.

When viewing the queues on the 2007 server, I see a ton of public folder messages stuck in a retry status in queue hub version 14.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: And there is a PF database on the Exchange 2010 server?  Just making sure I understand you before proceeding.

Comment: Yes, there is, thanks for checking. 

So I figued this one out... turns out that we had the 2007 IP server listed in a recieve connector on the 2010 server.. and that receive connector did not have "Exchange Server Authentication" selected, as it was only being used to relay scanner messages (scan to email).
Once I created a new receive connector, strictly for 2007 to 2010 on the 2010 server (type = internal), all the PFs finally replicated. Hope this helps someone out, but it was really just an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

the old mail server IP was listed in receive connector that did not have the Exchange Server Authentication checkbox selected on the authentication tab.
I removed the IP from that receive connector, and created a new one, type internal, strictly for 2007 to 2010 communication.